# Please advise on check gauges light on and battery gauge reads zero

Tags: battery, jeep, alternator, gauges

Saw this thread while investigating what sounds like the same problem with my jeep. The check gauge light came on and my battery gauge bottomed out. But  weird thing is, it ran fine. I drove it a few miles home, and turned it off, then started it again and the same thing happened real quick. What should I approach first since it's running ok. I do have some rust damage underneath. This jeep came from Detroit so its been in salt and snow for a long time, I just bought it and this is the first time its done anything weird. I could have a corroded connection or should I go right at Alternator being the culprit.
Thanks in advance for any advice,this is my first Jeep

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your alternator is the culprit as the engine is running on battery power. Before you purchase a new one, though, take it to your local Autozone, Pepboys, Checker, or the like and have them test it. They will do it for free. I take it since you didn't say the steering became hard, that the serpentine belt is still running correctly. If it was difficult to steer, this would be the issue.